# ui.bootstrap accordion remain open during ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

I'm using [ui.bootstrap accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) in an angular app to show show content to the user that I get with an ajax request from a server. I use long polling to fetch the data so they are refreshed automatically. However when an accordion from the group is open and the user reads the content, upon refresh accordion closes. How can I prevent this from happening? One idea is to be able to tell if any accordion is collapsed and stop the polling but I don't know how. I have read some articles with people taking advantage of `is-open` setting but I can't figure it out. Here is my code for the current accordion group.

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">

<uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="message in newMessages">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                title: {{message.attributes.subject}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {{message.attributes.body}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</uib-accordion-group>
```